# Single Sign 0n between DotNetNuke, Classic ASP app, ASP.NET app

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dotnetnuke

We run multiple apps to provide services to our members at our organization
1. DotNetNuke as CMS
2. Classic ASP  custom app for membership management and event management
3. ASP.NET app for providing online learning
4. Wordpress blog

Can somebody please suggest a way to enable Single Sign On in this kind of an environment.

I am looking for a solution which would enable adding any kind of application easily to the SSO in the future.

We host most of the apps, but there are some being hosted outside our environment as well.

All members are customers in different locations.

THanks

Answer (score 4):

You could use Live ID:

Windows Live ID with dotnetnuke:

http://www.datasprings.com/Resources/ArticlesInformation/DotNetNukewWindowsLiveAuthentication/tabid/828/language/en-US/Default.aspx

Windows Live ID with wordpress:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wliddev/thread/a34d1585-e602-4519-858c-0bb5ae02856d/

You could also use Open ID, the same as stackoverflow.

Live ID will be compatible with Open ID:

http://winliveid.spaces.live.com/

Have not been able to find a reference to use of Live ID with classic ASP.

Comment: A clarifying note: DotNetNuke has built in authentication providers for both Open ID and Live ID, you simply have to enable them. These providers were distributed starting with version 4.6.0, which is about two years old.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Windows Live ID to identify people with it.